# Why android HttpURLConnection cache the inputstream results?

Tags: java, android, xml, caching, inputstream

i'm trying to get a xml file but it seems to be cached.
there's my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://delibere.asl3.liguria.it/SVILUPPO/elenco_xml.asp?rand=" + new Random().nextInt()+"&Oggetto=" + text +"&TipoDocumento="+tipoDocumento);
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConn.setDefaultUseCaches(false); 
urlConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);   
urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Expires", "-1");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");     
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive"); 
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
Document doc = db.parse(is);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

thanks!

Comment: URL url="your url.com?x=xx"; 

InputStream is = null;
     
 is = url.openConnection().getInputStream(); 

try this dude.. then convert input stream to string

Answer (score 1):

You realize you aren't using your `HttpURLConnection`, right? If you want to get the `InputStream` using the `HttpURLConnection`, you need to call

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());
```

Also, I believe that it's standard to use Apache HttpClient for this sort of thing with Android, since it's built in and a much better API than the standard Java stuff.

Comment: you are right. i forgot the strange thing is it's working on emulator, but not on the phone (a htc desire)!

Comment: and of course, i forgot to add the code you remember me up on the question.

Comment: A more recent [android blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) says you should be using Apache HttpClient only for Froyo and below, but HttpURLConnection for everything after Froyo.

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like they have a solution with HttpClient that works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692814/httrequest-without-caching) You might try it, and HttpClient gives a bit more flexibility with other issues