# Why am I getting last response if my server doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, http-headers

I use simple code to get XML content.
but I have a trouble if my server doesn't work, I get last success response.

I tried all methods:

1. send every time another URI
2. setHeader Cache-Content [How to prevent Android from returning a cached response to my HTTP Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692814/httprequest-without-caching)
3. I tried even HttpURLConnection with GET.

but nothing helps

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
String fullPath = path + name;
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(fullPath);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

//....decode input string
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `response`?

Comment: Sorry that's my fault.I edited already.